# How to stop TinyMCE to change the image size after editing its name?

Tags: image, tinymce, size

I control the size of my image in a page by CSS **imgType**.

```
 <img class="imgType" style="..." src="/image1.jpg" alt="..." />
```

If I edit the image to change its name only (the fields width & height stay empty and save the content of the editor, tiny writes a value for both the width and height.

```
 <img class="imgType" style="..." src="/image2.jpg" alt="..." width="249" height="145" />
```

I tried to use **object_resizing : false**, but it does not do anything.

How can I stop tiny to write these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the image dimensions from the Insert/Edit Image dialog with:

```
image_dimensions: false
```

Docs:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#image_dimensions

Comment: Thank you!  The dimensions disappeared from the image editing panel and nothing is written... perfect.  So now in the dialog panel I only have the src and the title of the image.  How can I edit the class?

Comment: The image_class_list option adds a list of predefined classes to a dropdown in the dialog. See example here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#image_class_list